# Which eventype are generated when ELB logs are sent to S3

Tags: aws-lambda, elastic-load-balancer

Im creating a Lambda function that will get triggered when new ELB logs are sent to a S3 bucket.
I would prefer not to select "Object Created (All)" in the event type of my lambda function, I would rather limit it to the strict minimum:

The options are:

- Put
- Post
- Copy
- Complete Multipart Upload

Which one should I choose?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just test some options and find out! It's likely to be `Put`, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It's either `Put` or `Complete Multipart Upload`. It may be a combination of the two depending on the file sizes of each log file.